# don't update null input variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this stored procedur

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.News_Edite
(
  @Id bigint,
  @Title nvarchar(MAX),
  @Lile nvarchar(MAX),
  @Body nvarchar(MAX),
  @Type nvarchar(20),
  @Imgurl nvarchar(MAX),
  @Date nvarchar(50)
)
AS
update tbl_news
set
ne_title=@Title,
ne_lile=@Lile,
ne_body=@Body,
ne_type=@Type,
ne_imgurl=@Imgurl,
ne_date=@Date
where ne_id=@Id
RETURN
```

but i want dont update ne_imgurl if @Imgurl is null

what is the best way to include an input param in the **set** clause but exclude it if it is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **isNull** but I do not know what do you want to replace it with

for example :

```
ne_imgurl=isNull(@Imgurl, ''),
```

Comment: So you just need to do  it in this way : ne_imgurl=isNull(@Imgurl, ne_imgurl),

Answer (score 2):

Use the function [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx), then pass the original value as the 2nd parameter. What ISNULL does is it will return the first argument, unless the first argument is null, then it will return the second argument.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.News_Edite
(
  @Id bigint,
  @Title nvarchar(MAX),
  @Lile nvarchar(MAX),
  @Body nvarchar(MAX),
  @Type nvarchar(20),
  @Imgurl nvarchar(MAX),
  @Date nvarchar(50)
)
AS
update tbl_news
set
ne_title=@Title,
ne_lile=@Lile,
ne_body=@Body,
ne_type=@Type,
ne_imgurl=ISNULL(@Imgurl, ne_imgurl),
ne_date=@Date
where ne_id=@Id
RETURN
```

Answer (score 1):

use IF clause

```
IF( isNull(@Imgurl,0) ==0)
BEGIN
update tbl_news
set
ne_title=@Title,
ne_lile=@Lile,
ne_body=@Body,
ne_type=@Type,
ne_date=@Date
where ne_id=@Id
END

ELSE
BEGIN

update tbl_news
set
ne_title=@Title,
ne_lile=@Lile,
ne_body=@Body,
ne_type=@Type,
ne_imgurl=@Imgurl,
ne_date=@Date
where ne_id=@Id

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ISNULL or COALESCE function.

```
update
    tbl_news
set
    ne_title=@Title,
    ne_lile=@Lile,
    ne_body=@Body,
    ne_type=@Type,
    ne_imgurl=ISNULL(@Imgurl, ne_imgurl),
    ne_date=@Date
where
    ne_id=@Id
```